# MP4 not playing in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video, mp4

I'm testing some videos using "Video For Everybody" but for some reason my mp4 will not play in Safari. I also noticed that the Big Buck Bunny videos that VFE uses as the default are also not playing for me in Safari. Am I the only one having this issue?

http://v4e.thewikies.com/

Comment: Big Buck Bunny works for me with safari `version 7.0.4 (9537.76.4)` with no extensions installed.

Comment: I'm currently running 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) is this an old version?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm on Mac os X. According to this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), you are on the latest windows version, but it wasn't updated since 2012 and it is marked as old. I suppose there are not alot of people using safari on windows.

Comment: You are correct. According to my analytics over the last month I had 3 users running Safari on Windows.